# How to deal with this frustrating case of JWT auth bearer + async token?

Tags: api-reversing, api-hacking

Here's the case:

I'm analyzing an API and the way JWT was implemented seems to be anti-tampering. There's two components that must be there or there's an authentication error:

Auth Bearer -> Stays the same 'til the session expires

Async-Token -> Some fields Changes in every request made, it also expires.

So when I log in and do any operation (view/edit profile, check balance, top-up, etc) the server replies with a new Async-token, the app receives it and makes the same request with this token, only then the operation is made.

If I try to change values in the body, it doesn't do anything because the requests has already been made with both tokens. If I intercept and try to change the values (say user ID) before receiving the token, it returns an error. I tried to exploit the common flaws of JWT but this one appears to be very well secured.

Note: I can decode the tokens in base64 and see all the values except the signature.

Comment: Hi and welcome to RE.SE. What is the exact question? The question from the title is way too broad.